# Delphi IDE ignores environment variable change

Tags: delphi, environment-variables, delphi-xe2

We have a programm that changes an environment variable of the system by [using the function SetEnvironmentVariable(...), setting the environment variables and sending a broadcast message](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28254) to the system.

This works for all programs except the delphi ide (delphi xe2). We control the value by looking into the options - environment variables.

What we can see is the IDE flickering when sending the broadcast message, but the change of the environment variable does not work

Comment: I should note that the link you posted has this: *" .. the jist of what I read was that SetEnvironmentVariable was **completely irrelevant** for what I wanted to do. In order to achieve my ends all I needed to do was set the required value in the registry ... "*. (emphasis original). I wonder how did you concluded that it *"works for all programs"*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed to notice in the post, that I also set the value in the registry. (Change id by now)

Answer (score 2):

It's up to each application to listen to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and take appropriate action. It seems that the Delphi IDE is not updating its cache of environment variables.

You've done all you can. The only way the behaviour can be changed is from within the IDE. You will need to restart the IDE.